# MySqlException was unhandled when using count on SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

When my SQL query has a count function in the query it does not want to display the data in the DBGRID and I'm getting a "MySqlException was unhandled" error. As soon as I remove the count function it runs smoothly and displays the data on the DB grid.

Code below:

```vb
Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("Server info")

Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(a.client_id), a.CLIENT_ID,b.c_name, b.C_surname FROM tblinv_info a JOIN  tblclientinfo b ON a.CLIENT_ID = b.CLIENT_ID WHERE extract(year from a.inv_date) in ('2018','2019') AND a.Client_id = b.Client_id GROUP BY a.client_id ORDER BY count(a.client_id) desc LIMIT 10", connection)

cmd.CommandTimeout = 500

Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)

Dim table As New DataTable()

adapter.Fill(table)

dbreport.DataSource = table
```

Any idea on why this could be happening? I'm running the program in Visual Studio coding with VB.NET and using a MySql database. The SQL command runs fine on the localhost database.

> Error:  Error code is as follows: An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.

Comment: if you use count you need to group by all the selected fields

Comment: As the above comment suggests, your current query is invalid.  Do you want help with fixing the query, or with adding try-catch logic to your VB.net code to cope with the current query?

Comment: Wow thanks for the awesome feedback. I just assumed it was correct displaying the correct results on the localhost database. I will see if i can fix my query by adding the group by clause

Comment: @AndrichPienaar what you should always do is to run your SQL in the query editor. And when it actually runs, then try in the code

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are well.
I think, the problem is, in the Select query, all the fields have a name column, but the counter, don't.

```
    SELECT COUNT(a.client_id), a.CLIENT_ID,b.c_name, b.C_surname ...
```

And, the filler and data source don't know where to place the counter column.
Set As name to counter column.

```
   SELECT COUNT(a.client_id) AS Counter1, a.CLIENT_ID,b.c_name, b.C_surname
   adapter.Fill(table)
   dbreport.DataSource = table
```

Comment: Hi I updated the code to the following  Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT COUNT(a.client_id) AS Counter1, a.CLIENT_ID,b.c_name, b.C_surname FROM tblinv_info a JOIN  tblclientinfo b ON a.CLIENT_ID = b.CLIENT_ID WHERE extract(year from a.inv_date) in ('2018','2019') AND a.Client_id = b.Client_id ORDER BY count(a.client_id) desc LIMIT 10", connection).  I am still getting the same error

Comment: @AndrichPienaar Plese, update your question and not post code in comments

Comment: This is good practice but not an issue in this case

Answer (score 0):

You have missing your fields in `group by`

Run this in SQL query editor

```sql
SELECT COUNT(a.client_id) as cnt, a.CLIENT_ID, b.c_name, b.C_surname -- NOTE CHANGE
FROM
    tblinv_info a JOIN
    tblclientinfo b ON a.CLIENT_ID = b.CLIENT_ID 
WHERE
   extract(year from a.inv_date) in ('2018','2019') AND 
   a.Client_id = b.Client_id 
GROUP BY
   a.client_id, 
   b.c_name, -- NOTE CHANGE
   b.C_surname -- NOTE CHANGE 
ORDER BY 
   cnt desc  -- NOTE CHANGE
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks for assisting! I updated my code to what you provided and it still gives a MySqlException was unhandled error.  The additional information on the error says Fatal error encountered attempting to read the dataset,  The issue also shows at the  adapter.fill(table) part of the code. Any idea what I can change to get this working

Comment: @AndrichPienaar Try adding `sqlcommand.commandtype = CommandType.Text`

Comment: @AndrichPienaar Also, we already said, this is not a good practice to leave select like this `COUNT(a.client_id)` -- change to `COUNT(a.client_id) as xxx` where `xxx` is any name you select for it, i.e. `groupCount`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your query timed out during execution.
You can increase command timeout using CommandTimeout.

```vb
cmd.CommandTimeout = 120; // 2 minutes (example)
```

Detailed code:

```vb
Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("My Server info")
Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(a.client_id), a.CLIENT_ID,b.c_name, b.C_surname FROM tblinv_info a JOIN  tblclientinfo b ON a.CLIENT_ID = b.CLIENT_ID WHERE extract(year from a.inv_date) in ('2018','2019') AND a.Client_id = b.Client_id GROUP BY a.client_id ORDER BY count(a.client_id) desc LIMIT 10", connection)
cmd.CommandTimeout = 120
Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim table As New DataTable()
adapter.Fill(table)
dbreport.DataSource = table
```

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. I copied over the code and entered my server info but I still get the same error as i have been getting previously. Error code is as follows: An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll

Additional information: Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.

Comment: Have you tried setting a longer CommandTimeout?
For example: `cmd.CommandTimeout = Integer.MaxValue`.
What MySQL Server version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally got the problem sorted.

The mysql.data.dll file I was using as a reference (ver6.3.5.0) was too old.

I downloaded version 6.4.4.0  and removed the old reference and now it displaying perfectly.